# C# .net console application unable to read from app.config after deployment

Tags: c#, .net

I created simple .net framework based console application,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Key0" value="Configuration Example 0"/>
    <add key="Key1" value="Configuration Example 1"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The code below is working fine only debugging or running:

```
var title = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key0"];
var language = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"];
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key0 :'{0}'     \n Key1 :'{1}'  ", key0, Key1));
```

---

from visual studio , I have use publish option , after publish , one folder and setup.exe is created , I use that setup.exe to deploy the application

I modify the (ConsoleApp2.exe.config.deploy) settings..

But application is not reading new values, its shows only old values.

Any idea , what is the way to achieve it ,

Simply, I want to read some values from app.config after deploying the app, when I debug or running using VS , its working , but after install using setup.exe(Created from Publish option), its unable to read from configuration file .  for configuration I can only see one file , which is (ConsoleApp2.exe.config.deploy).

Comment: What is the name of the file you're modifying?

Comment: ConsoleApp2.exe.config.deploy ,, this is only file I found containing the app.config information

Comment: That's the wrong file. That sounds like part of the installer. The actual config file would be named ConsoleApp2.exe.config and it would be found in the program folder after deployment. If you are publishing the project, are you actually running the installer or are you just copying it somewhere and running the app from there? You're doing something wrong but it's hard to say what exactly. You should provide a DETAILED explanation of how you're deploying and running the app.

Comment: from visual studio , I have use publish option ,  after publish , one folder and setup.exe is created , I use that  setup.exe to deploy the application

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Update the question to provide all the relevant information. Also, notice how I put "DETAILED" in all caps.

Comment: When you publish an app you are provided with a folder and setup.exe as you mentioned. Use setup.exe to install the app to your specified path and go to the installation path and modify the config file in that location. Just make sure you are modifying the correct config file and not the one from the initial folder that came with setup.exe. You have to make sure that the app is closed or exit properly before reopening to reflect the config changes

Comment: When I run Setup.exe , it never show any path , and also did not any option to specify, I search in program files , its not there too.   how to find where its installed ?